# Excel VBA code seeing formula instead of cell result

Tags: excel, vba

This only sees the formula, not the result of the formula - please help!
(There is a formula in W2 that shows a value)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next

    If Target.Cells.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("w2"), Target)

    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 20 Then

        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook

    End If

End Sub

Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()

    Dim xOutApp As Object

    Dim xOutMail As Object

    Dim xMailBody As String

    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)

    xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _

              "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _

              "This is line 2"

    On Error Resume Next

    With xOutMail

        .To = "Email Address"

        .CC = ""

        .BCC = ""

        .Subject = "send by cell value test"

        .Body = xMailBody

        .Display   'or use .Send

    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set xOutMail = Nothing

    Set xOutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the formula in `W2`?

Comment: Which line isn't behaving how you expect it to? (use F8 to step through the code line by line)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work OK here. This sample code behaves exactly as I would expect.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 On Error Resume Next
 If Target.Cells.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub
 Set xRg = Intersect(Range("b10"), Target)

 If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

 If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 20 Then
     Call ToyMail(Target.Value, Target.Formula)
 End If
 Call ToyMail(Target.Value, Target.Formula)
End Sub

Sub ToyMail(x, y)
  Debug.Print "Mail called ", x, y
End Sub
```

First thing to try if your version isn't working is comment out "On Error Resume Next" so that you get to see any runtime errors that occur and step through it in the debugger.